# Arrays.asList( ... ) in .Net

Tags: java, .net

I am looking for the simplest way to write the following Java code

```
Arrays.asList(1L);
```

in .Net

Thanks

Comment: There's no need to write this code at all in .NET since a .NET array is already a fixed-size `IList<T>`. The closest literal translation of the code in your question would just be `new[] { 1L };`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
int[] a = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
List<int> list = a.ToList(); // Requires LINQ extension method

//Another way...
List<int> listNew = new List<int>(new []{ 1, 2, 3 }); // Does not require LINQ
```

Note that `LINQ` is available in `.NET 3.5` or higher.

**More information**

- [Enumerable.ToList Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)
- [C# ToList Extension Method](http://www.dotnetperls.com/tolist)

Comment: (in System.Linq - just to complete the answer)

Comment: You are right, that is the `namespace` for the method. Thanks.

Comment: But this is not the equivalent. Arrays.asList(T...) this mean that You don't have to create an array and then create list from it.

Comment: The `List` returned by `asList` is a view rather than a copy of the array. I suspect that in most cases that isn't what you want (unless you want to `Collections.shufflle` the array). Is there any `AsIList` [extension] method?

Comment: @Tom Hawtin - tackline, there is no extension method as `AsIList`. I am not sure if .NET offers a `view` feature as offered by `asList`... Maybe some can clarify.

Comment: @Tom, @Devendra: This entire question -- and most of the answers -- are completely moot. The array type in .NET implements the `IList<T>` interface, so arrays already give you the functionality that's provided by `Arrays.asList` in Java.

Comment: @LukeH, but is there an equivalent of `asList` in .NET?

Comment: @Devendra: No, because it's completely unnecessary. `Arrays.asList` returns a fixed-size `List<T>` (an interface, the Java equivalent of .NET's `IList<T>`). The array type in .NET is already a fixed-size `IList<T>`. If you want to mimic the *exact* syntax of `Arrays.asList` in .NET then I'll update my answer with an implementation.

Comment: @LukeH, I wonder why this method has been created in `java` then? Another point to ponder is what happens to the bridged array (in java) when a `List.add()` is called.

Comment: @Devendra: Because arrays in Java don't implement `List<T>`; that's why the `Arrays.asList` method is needed (to provide a `List<T>` wrapper over the array). Arrays in .NET do implement `IList<T>`, and that's why the equivalent of `Arrays.asList` *isn't* needed in .NET.

Comment: @Devendra: No problem. By the way, if you call `add` on the list returned from `Arrays.asList` then you'll get an `UnsupportedOperationException`. (Similarly, you'll get a `NotSupportedException` in .NET if you call `Add` on an array cast to `IList<T>`.)

Answer (score 8):

Since arrays already implement `IList<T>` in .NET then there's not really any need for an equivalent of `Arrays.asList`. Just use the array directly, or if you feel the need to be explicit about it:

```
IList<int> yourList = (IList<int>)existingIntArray;
IList<int> anotherList = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
```

This is about as close as you'll get to the Java original: fixed-size, and writes pass through to the underlying array (although in this case the list and the array are exactly the same object).

Further to the comments on [Devendra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5259413/arrays-aslist-in-net/5259471#5259471), if you really want to use exactly the same syntax in .NET then it'll look something like this (although it's a pretty pointless exercise, in my opinion).

```
IList<int> yourList = Arrays.AsList(existingIntArray);
IList<int> anotherList = Arrays.AsList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

// ...

public static class Arrays
{
    public static IList<T> AsList<T>(params T[] source)
    {
        return source;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

not sure whether you want to convert an array to a list as per Devendra's answer or create a new populated list in one go if it's the second then this'll do it:

```
new List<int>(){1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

In fact the braces syntax to populate collections will populate Arrays, dictionaries etc...

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of that static method looks like this.

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a) {
return new ArrayList<T>(a);
}
```

The equivalent for You wold be write same utility class with method asList in C# or use the solution presented by Massif.

```
public static class Arrays {
      public static List<T> asList<T>(params T[] a)
        {
            return new List<T>(a);

        }
}
```

Comment: Note that the `ArrayList` there is **not** `java.util.ArrayList` (poor naming but that's the way it must stay [due to serial form]).

Comment: And where did you found i my example something like java.util.ArrayList ?

Comment: 1 Because the answer is highly misleading. (Also I note inappropriately suggests using "`as`" instead of "`to`".) And there's a better older answer (that has just acquired a -1).

Comment: @Tom: I do not comprehend what is so highly misleading, I've presented the way how it is implemented in Java, then wrote the equivalent in C# and suggested that OP can use the other solution. Of-course the best answer for question would be new List<long>(){1L}; If the OP is focused on result not the way it is done. The suggestion, was from Java developer not from my side ;).

Answer (score 0):

To create a single-item array, you simply do this:

```
long[] arr = new[] { 1L };
```

Answer (score 0):

```
return new List<int> {A,B};
```